# Future Perfect about Past

Tags: future-perfect

I heard we could say The Future Perfect Tense

> You **will have read** in the newspapers about the conclusion of this agreement.

meaning

> You **must have read** in the newspapers about the conclusion of this agreement.

Is it true that we can use **"will have V3"** instead of **"must have V3"**?

Comment: Certainly. But they give the sentence different meanings.

Comment: Tenses are usually not interchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

It's very unfortunate that we are stuck with the traditional classification of *will do* as a "future tense" (and *will have done* as "future perfect tense")

Really, these are modal expressions, like *may do* and *should have done*, with a range of meanings, one of which is futurity. Like other modals, they can have **epistemic** meanings  (about the speaker's or hearer's knowledge or understanding) as well as **deontic** meanings (about how the world is).

*You will have read in the newspapers* has an epistemic meaning, something like "I guess/assume that you have read in the newspapers".

*You must have read in the newspapers*, with a different modal, has a slightly different epistemic meaning, something like "I deduce/am certain that you have read in the newspapers".